# Find set of solutions $S_z:=\{y \in\mathbb{R}^{N}: y'z=\iota_N ' z\}$, $ z\in\mathbb{R}^N$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How to characterize $S_z:=\{y \in\mathbb{R}^{N}: y'z=\iota_N ' z\}$, $ z\in\mathbb{R}^N$? 
Is there also a general way for more complex equations $y'\beta(z)=\iota'z$ where $\beta(z)\in\mathbb{R}^N$ is a function of $z$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ z\in\mathbb{R}^N$ be such that $\iota'z=k$. If $z=0$, $S_z=\mathbb{R}^N$. Otherwise there is $i\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$ such that $z_i\neq0$. Define $S_{z,i}=\left\{y_i:=(y, \tilde{y}): y \in\mathbb{R}^{N-1}, \tilde{y}=\frac{k-y'z_{-i}}{z_i} \right\}$ where $z_{-i} \in\mathbb{R}^{N-1}$ is the vector $z$ without entry $z_i$. 
Obviously $S_{z,i} \subset S_{z}$ and $S_{z}=\cup_i S_{z,i}$.

Analogous way for more complex function.